# How to clear input fields after adding a new element?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an array with the students.

I have the implementation of the addition of students.

Question: how to clean up after pressing the field? Fields must be cleaned so that when you try to enter new values ​​were not set to the old values.

Tried everything, nothing works. Neither the `<form>` -> `<button type = "reset">`, or the selectors ...

What can be done to solve this problem?

index.html

```html
......
<!-- add new student -->
<br>
    <input v-model="students.name" placeholder="surname">
    <select v-model="students.group">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <input v-model="students.year" placeholder="Bitrh year">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="students.done">
    <label>done</label>
    <input v-model.number="students.mark" type="number" placeholder="mark">
    <button type="reset" @click="addStudent()">add to array</button>
</div>
<!-- /add new student -->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="/index.js"></script>
```

index.js

```js
let students = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: "Test",
        group: "1",
        year: "1985",
        done: true,
        mark: 4,
    },
]

var app = new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        students: [],
        search: '',
        stud: students.slice(),
    },
    methods: {
        deleteStudent(studId) {
            this.stud = this.stud.filter(elem => {
                return elem.id != studId;
            });
        },
        addStudent() {
            const id = this.stud.length + 1;
            this.stud.push({ id, ...this.students });
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know vue, but you can always select all inputs and set it's value on '' :
`document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => input.value='')`

in best case apply it to container so sth like that:

`document.querySelector('.formClassName').querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => input.value='')`

Answer (score 0):

Just use following:

```
deleteStudent(studId) {
  this.stud.splice(students.id, 1)
}
```

You can `splice` something based on it's id the 1 after the comma is that it deletes 1 stud-data from your id.

Comment: I've still answerd some similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69707589/vue-remove-loop-rendered-component-from-dom/69719379#69719379 - you can check that out too, it's a more detailed answer!

Comment: I think you meant to write function before "deleteStudent".

Comment: Yes, of course! Sorry - thanks for updating!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a v-model on your form and let the user enter some data, you should pass an *initial **object*** to your inputs. And when the user submits the form, you'll `push` that data to your array, following to reset your initial object.

So this implementation will help you:

```html
<!-- add new student -->
<br>
    <input v-model="initialState.name" placeholder="surname">
    <select v-model="initialState.group">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <input v-model="initialState.year" placeholder="Bitrh year">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="initialState.done">
    <label>done</label>
    <input v-model.number="initialState.mark" type="number" placeholder="mark">
    <button type="reset" @click="addStudent()">add to array</button>
</div>
<!-- /add new student -->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="/index.js"></script>
```

```js
var app = new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        students: [],
        initialState: {
          id: '',
          name: '',
          group: '',
          year: '',
          done: true,
          mark: 0
        },
        search: '',
    },
    methods: {
        deleteStudent(studId) {
            this.students = this.students.filter(elem => {
                return elem.id != studId;
            });
        },
        addStudent() {
            const id = this.students.length + 1;
            this.students.push({ id, this.initialState });
            this.initialState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
              id: '',
              name: '',
              group: '',
              year: '',
              done: true,
              mark: 0
            }));
        }
    }
})
```